# Oracle Forms: Why can't I add a new Type Spec?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I wish to add a Type Spec to an Oracle Form. Unfortunately, this option is disabled in the "New Program Unit" dialog:

[image: Oracle Forms: New Program Unit Dialog]

Does anyone know how to add a Type Spec to an Oracle Form?

Version of Oracle Forms Builder: Forms [32 Bit] Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production)

Comment: I've seen this dialog >1000 times but never gave a second thought to the greyed-out options... can't think of any reason they should be there in the first place, since you can't create those things in an Oracle form anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never created one with forms but one way to enable the type spec option is: from the Object Navigator expand the database objects node. Then select PL/SQL Stored Program Units now click the create button (so it brings up the dialogue box shown in your screen shot)

However this time the type spec option will be enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about that! :) However, I believe this option creates the Type Spec **in the database**, not the form. Unfortunately, I need a Type Spec **in the form** so that it can access the libraries attached to the form.

Comment: I don't think you can create client side types using this method. This option (along with the Type wizard which does the same job) only creates type on the database. If you haven't already done so, more information on the type wizard can be found in the forms help under "Type Wizard Overview"